# How to make a verify ban command?

Tags: discord.py

Right, I want to make it so when I do "/ban @user reason" the bot responds with an embed saying are you sure you want to ban this user and reacts to its message with a tick, and awaits for the reaction off of the person who made the ban.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please include your code, approaches and errors you face. Nobody is going to code all of this for you. You may also take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```py
@bot.command(name="ban")
async def ban(ctx, member, reason=""):
    if not ctx.message.mentions:
        await ctx.channel.send("You must mention a user to use this command")
    embed = discord.Embed(
        title="Confirm ban",
        description=f"Are you sure you want to ban {member.mention}",
        color=0xff0000
    )
    message = await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed)
    await message.add_reaction(u"\U0001F44D")

    def check(pay):
        pay.member == member and pay.message_id == ctx.message.id

    await bot.wait_for("raw_reaction_add", check=check)
    await member.ban(reason=reason)
```